# mfcc in keras lstm error: Expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, lstm, mfcc

How do i solve this problem?

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_10: expected
>   ndim=3, found ndim=2

https://github.com/zahiruddinnorzain/keras_lstm_mfcc

dataset link : [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14o5djf8L7OjYLnoABg4rDi3kVWyGecRA)

I got the above mentioned error when running this code. This code will training the mfcc data of digit, from 0 to 9 with 13 coefficient.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

from keras.optimizers import SGD
np.random.seed(1337)
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
#from SpeechResearch import loadData

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas

'exception_verbosity = high'
batch_size = 5
hidden_units = 13
nb_classes = 10
print('Loading data...')


# load train dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("train.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_train = dataset[:,0:13] #.astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,13]
# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)


# load test dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("test.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_test = dataset[:,0:13] #.astype(float)
y_test = dataset[:,13]
# encode class values as integers
encoder2 = LabelEncoder()
encoder2.fit(y_test)
encoded_Y2 = encoder.transform(y_test)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y2)



#(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = loadData.load_mfcc(10, 2)

print(len(X_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(X_test), 'test sequences')
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)
print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
print('y_test shape:', y_test.shape)
print(y_test)
print('Build model...')

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(output_dim=hidden_units, init='uniform', inner_init='uniform',
               forget_bias_init='one', activation='tanh', inner_activation='sigmoid', input_shape=X_train.shape[1:]))


model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

print("Train...")
model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=3, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), show_accuracy=True)
score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test,
                            batch_size=batch_size,
                            show_accuracy=True)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

Comment: Which line did you get the error? It's quite clear, the input parameter is the wrong type.

Comment: There are many error. As Upasana Mittal said, The error I was facing because, I hadn't reshaped the data before inputing in LSTM. The second error was faced because, in updated version of keras, There is no term like show_accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around your code and here is the working code. There were many errors I had to face and warning were also there as you seemed to use old version of keras.
Below code is as per the updated version of keras:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np

from keras.optimizers import SGD
np.random.seed(1337)
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM
#from SpeechResearch import loadData

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas

'exception_verbosity = high'
batch_size = 5
hidden_units = 13
nb_classes = 10
print('Loading data...')


# load train dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("train.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_train = dataset[:,0:13] #.astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,13]
# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
# y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)


# load test dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("test.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
X_test = dataset[:,0:13] #.astype(float)
y_test = dataset[:,13]
# encode class values as integers
encoder2 = LabelEncoder()
encoder2.fit(y_test)
encoded_Y2 = encoder.transform(y_test)
# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
# y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y2)



#(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = loadData.load_mfcc(10, 2)

print(len(X_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(X_test), 'test sequences')
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)
# print('y_train shape:', y_train.shape)
# print('y_test shape:', y_test.shape)
# print(y_test)
print('Build model...')

X_train = X_train.reshape(1, X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1])
X_test = X_test.reshape(1, X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1])
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print('X_test shape:', X_test.shape)

Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y2, nb_classes)
print(Y_train.shape)
print(Y_test.shape)
Y_train = Y_train.reshape(1, Y_train.shape[0], Y_train.shape[1])
Y_test = Y_test.reshape(1, Y_test.shape[0], Y_test.shape[1])

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=hidden_units, kernel_initializer='uniform',
           unit_forget_bias='one', activation='tanh', recurrent_activation='sigmoid', input_shape=(None,X_train.shape[2]),     return_sequences=True))


model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())

print("Train...")
model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=3)
score, acc = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test,
                        batch_size=batch_size)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

The error you were facing because, you hadn't reshaped the data before inputing in LSTM
The second error was faced because, in updated version of keras, There is no term like `show_accuracy`. We just need to define `metrics = ['accuracy]` while compiling model in `model.compile`
The third error was the way we define input shape in input layer. 
Rest, You can read and let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: thank you for helping me with this problem, you are my savior.